# Performing a correlational analysis on ASV tables and Metadata tables

Tags: python, pandas, metadata, pearson-correlation

I am extremely nervous to post because I am a beginner and took on a bit more than I could chew. Nonetheless, the problem is that I am working on a project where I write a script to correlate the environmental effects on certain organisms given different samples, their environments, and the abundancy of the producers in each organism. I have an excel sheet of Amplicon Sequence Variants with the relative abundance of each ASV, as well as a sheet of the environments they were in (the way I will match the data is with a sample-id). The problem is that every line of code I try seems to throw a different error.

I tried the following

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import pearsonr, spearmanr



asv_table = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\gunne\Downloads\Page1_ASV.csv",encoding='latin1')
metadata = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\gunne\Downloads\2021_metadata_csv.csv",encoding='latin1')




abundances = asv_table.iloc[1:,1:].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
top_producers = abundances[:20].index
asv_data = asv_table[top_producers]



merged_data = pd.merge(asv_data, metadata, on="sample_id")



results = {}
for producer in top_producers:
    for factor in metadata.columns:
        r_pearson, _ = pearsonr(merged_data[producer], merged_data[factor])
        r_spearman, _ = spearmanr(merged_data[producer], merged_data[factor])
        results[(producer, factor)] = {"Pearson correlation": r_pearson, "Spearman correlation": r_spearman}



for (producer, factor), values in results.items():
    print(f"{producer} vs {factor}: Pearson = {values['Pearson correlation']:.2f}, Spearman = {values['Spearman correlation']:.2f}")
```

Currently, the error I get is that the code cannot sum the columns because the columns and rows are not solely numerical (the sample-id column and ASV row need to be present to match the data). This means that I cannot identify the twenty most abundant producers to correlate. I could to this on the excel sheet using conditional formatting, however I need it in code so that I can use that data for the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

If you shaped your data a little bit differently you could use [pandas corr method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) to avoid using for loops.

However, there's no information about format of these csv files so it's hard for us to propose a copy-paste ready solution.

Comment: Apologies. The ASV table is formatted so that the sample is the rows and the ASV is the columns. The metadata is formatted so that the sample is the rows and the specific environment is the columns (such as temp or pH).